# How to get AWS ARN of resource (IAM role) generated through Terraform to use in Java code of Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-iam

I'm writing an AWS Lambda function which is basically Java code doing some stuff. We're using Terraform to create the resources in AWS and we've created IAM role/policies through TF. I need the IAM Role's ARN that's created through TF to use in my Java code (Lambda) to use in AWS STS AssumeRole call.

Is there any way to get the Role's ARN in the Java code?

Even if I define a variable to output.tf how can I access that in the code? Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoever that has downvoted this question - would you please be kind enough to explain the reason behind the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any values inside your lambda function through `environment` argument in terraform.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  count = var.create_lambda_function ? 1 : 0

  filename         = "${var.lambda_function_name}.${var.archive_type}"
  function_name    = "${var.lambda_function_name}-${lower(var.environment)}"
  role             = var.role_arn
  handler          = var.handler
  timeout          = var.timeout
  runtime          = var.runtime
  layers           = var.add_layers ? aws_lambda_layer_version.pymysql_lambda_layer.*.arn : []
  source_code_hash = one(data.archive_file.lambda_function_zip.*.output_base64sha256)


  environment {
    variables = {
      ROLE_ARN = var.role_arn
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you already know how to get the IAM role ARN through input variable (`var.role_arn`). If you are creating the IAM role in a different module, you can access it through `module` output or you can refer the role arn as `aws_iam_role.example.arn` if you are creating the role on the same location where lambda function code exists.

Once this is done, you can now call the environment variable `ROLE_ARN` inside your Java code.

Comment: Yes, I can get hold of Role ARN within TF code. And I guess in the Java code all I have to do to get this environment variable is the following code, right? String roleARN = System.getenv("ROLE_ARN");  I'm referring this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-retrieve

Comment: Exactly, you need to pass the environment variable the same way as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @saurabh-patil If it worked, acceptance of my answer would be much appreciated